# Why am I getting an empty array from MongoCollection::find

Tags: php, mongodb

When I use the following PHP code:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('mylocalmap_development');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'stores');
$cursor = $collection->find();
var_dump($cursor); exit;
```

..I get an empty array:

```
object(MongoCursor)#82 (0) { }
```

But if I do the following, I can see that there is a record in that collection:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12
connecting to: test
> use mylocalmap_development
switched to db mylocalmap_development
> db.stores.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54aa9626adc9f013088b4567"), "name" : "The Greengrocer", "address" : "123 Fake Street", "city" : "Stirling" }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm following the documentation as far as I can see anyway

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Comment: It's a `MongoCursor` object and not an array just like the "dump" told you. Look at methods and the general documentation for how to iterate a cursor returned from the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `iterator_to_array($cursor)` to see the content of the cursor. If there is a record, the array will not be empty:

```
var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));
```

Comment: I think I just didn't recognize that it wasn't an array. Thanks though, I wasn't away of this function.